# How to change the language on the spinner in the application

Tags: android, localization

I want the user to change the UI language in the spinner

I got 3 languages

English
Malaysian
Simplified Chinese

I got all the strings translated in English, Malaysian, and Chinese

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
Intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.package.address","com.package.address.Video"));
```

to:

```
Video.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.package.address","com.package.address.Video"));
```

By using `Intent`, which is a class name, you were accidentally making a static reference to the method, instead of calling it from the instance you created earlier.

Comment: how do you call another activity from an image button ?

Answer (score 0):

you can start the new activity like this

```
Intent Video = new Intent(address.this,Video.class);
startActivity(Video);
```

You can't use the static method Intent.setComponent instead try video.setComponent